# To toggle between two applications in Appium on same android device

Tags: android, automation, appium

I have a SPA(multiple pages) app and another messaging app. Flow desired in Android:

1. open SPA app, click on widget.
2. open messaging app, get an OTP(one-time password).
3. open the SPA app from where I left, and put in the OTP.

Is this possible? Because once I open the messaging app after SPA, I have to override the existing Appium session.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, I hope that's OK. When you say "SPA", do you mean "single-page app"? And when you say "OTP", do you mean "one-time password"? Those letters can mean other things too, so it would help readers like me if you explained your acronyms when you first use them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the things, edited, hope that makes them clear now.

Comment: Hi Saumya, did you find any solution for your problem? If yes, please post it here.